# computing condition median with groupby

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to figure out an efficient way (in regards to # of lines of code) to compute the condition median of a dataframe while using the group by statement.

below is the structure of my data:

```
id     date    exp    d_x    yield
 1     2/5     3/10    .2     0.01
 1     2/5     3/10    .48    0.09
 1     2/5     3/10    .67    0.10
 1     2/5     3/10    .77    0.04
 1     2/5     4/15    .2     0.31
 1     2/5     4/15    .65    0.10
...    ...     ...     ..     ...
29     5/4     10/20   .24    0.21
```

What I basically want is:
A new column - called "median_yield" that is the median of all the yields with d_x < .5 for each group.

```
grouping = (id, date, exp)
```

What I've tried is the below:

```
df.query("d_x < .5").groupby(['id', 'date', 'Expiration'], as_index=False)['yield'].transform('median')
```

However, the results are good, but for d_x > .5, the results are Nan.

Desired output:

```
id     date    exp    d_x    yield   median_y
 1     2/5     3/10    .2     0.01    0.5
 1     2/5     3/10    .48    0.09    0.5
 1     2/5     3/10    .67    0.10    0.5
 1     2/5     3/10    .77    0.04    0.5
 1     2/5     4/15    .2     0.31    0.31
 1     2/5     4/15    .65    0.10    0.31
...    ...     ...     ..     ...     ....
29     5/4     10/20   .24    0.21    ....
```

SAMPLE EXAMPLE:
dataframe:

```
df1 = {'id' : [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       'date' : ["2/5", "2/5", "2/5", "2/5", "2/5", "3/5", "3/5", "3/5", 
                 "3/5", "3/5"],
        'exp' : ["3/10", "3/10", "3/10", "3/10", "3/10", "4/15", "4/15", 
                 "4/15", "4/15", "4/15"],
        'd_x' : [.2, .431, .501, .56, .77, .10, .15, .61, .32, .91],
        'yield' : [.01, .04, .05, .10, .05, .012, .10, .20, .12, .05]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)

df1["median_y"] = df1.query("d_x < .5")\
                        .groupby(['id', 'date', 'exp'])\
                        ['yield'].transform('median')
```

Desired Output of sample data:

```
id     date    exp    d_x    yield   median_y
 1     2/5     3/10    .2     0.01    0.025
 1     2/5     3/10    .431   0.04    0.025
 1     2/5     3/10    .501   0.05    0.025
 1     2/5     3/10    .56    0.1     0.025
 1     2/5     3/10    .77    0.05    0.025
 2     3/5     4/15    .1     0.012   0.1
 2     3/5     4/15    .15    0.1     0.1
 2     3/5     4/15    .61    0.2     0.1
 2     3/5     4/15    .32    0.12    0.1
 2     3/5     4/15    .91    0.05    0.1
```

Comment: Can you construct a complete small dataset that will output the 'Nan'?  And, then show the desired output from this small dataset.

Comment: @ScottBoston, please see what've you requested in the updates! thanks!

Comment: When you're using ``query ``, you select those values and only those so pandas does not know what to do with the other values ``df_x >= .5``. What behavior do you expect to see instead of the NaN's ?

Comment: I want to compute a condition median but "paste" those medians over the values that didn't fit the criteria as well.. not sure how else to word it :x ... basically compute a median of only d_x < .5 but apply it to all the rows that are in the group

Comment: Well are you sure about the result you are expected in your question ?  The `Desired Output's median column` do not have good valu eto me

Comment: @BenoitDrogou, can you elaborate please?

Comment: Well you are trying to calculate the median of the column `d_x` grouped by `id`, `date` and `exp` right ?

Comment: `transform` returns a series with the length of the grouped data.  Since you have filtered the original dataframe then grouped, transform is giving you back records for that filter data only.  In this situation, I think it is best if you use `agg` and join back to the original dataset.

Comment: @BenoitDrogou, yes, but I only want to compute the median only using rows with d_x < .5, and save that median in each row as a column

Comment: My bad, I just realized there are 2 examples with 2 Desired Dataframe. Sorry for useless comments

Comment: @BenoitDrogou, no apologies needed, thank you for taking your time to view the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
df1.query("d_x < .5").groupby(['id', 'date', 'exp'])['yield']\
    .agg('median').rename('median_y').reset_index().merge(df1)
```

Instead of using `transform` use `agg` then join back using `merge` to the original dataframe on grouped columns.

Output:

```
   id date   exp  median_y    d_x  yield
0   1  2/5  3/10     0.025  0.200  0.010
1   1  2/5  3/10     0.025  0.431  0.040
2   1  2/5  3/10     0.025  0.501  0.050
3   1  2/5  3/10     0.025  0.560  0.100
4   1  2/5  3/10     0.025  0.770  0.050
5   2  3/5  4/15     0.100  0.100  0.012
6   2  3/5  4/15     0.100  0.150  0.100
7   2  3/5  4/15     0.100  0.610  0.200
8   2  3/5  4/15     0.100  0.320  0.120
9   2  3/5  4/15     0.100  0.910  0.050
```

---

answer Comment:

```
df1.merge(df1.query("d_x < .5").groupby(['id', 'date', 'exp'])['yield']\
   .agg('median').rename('median_y').reset_index())
```

Output:

```
   id date   exp    d_x  yield  median_y
0   1  2/5  3/10  0.200  0.010     0.025
1   1  2/5  3/10  0.431  0.040     0.025
2   1  2/5  3/10  0.501  0.050     0.025
3   1  2/5  3/10  0.560  0.100     0.025
4   1  2/5  3/10  0.770  0.050     0.025
5   2  3/5  4/15  0.100  0.012     0.100
6   2  3/5  4/15  0.150  0.100     0.100
7   2  3/5  4/15  0.610  0.200     0.100
8   2  3/5  4/15  0.320  0.120     0.100
9   2  3/5  4/15  0.910  0.050     0.100
```

Comment: thank you so much scott! side note - i see that median_y gets placed in the center randomly(? - i assume), is that true, and is there any way to control that without a new line of code?

Answer (score 2):

You may change your command a little to get desired output as follows. (*I didn't know that you edited adding new sample. On your new sample*):

```
df1['median_y'] = (df1['yield'].where(df1.d_x < .5)
                              .groupby([df1.id, df1.date, df1.exp])
                              .transform('median'))


Out[232]:
   id date   exp    d_x  yield  median_y
0   1  2/5  3/10  0.200  0.010     0.025
1   1  2/5  3/10  0.431  0.040     0.025
2   1  2/5  3/10  0.501  0.050     0.025
3   1  2/5  3/10  0.560  0.100     0.025
4   1  2/5  3/10  0.770  0.050     0.025
5   2  3/5  4/15  0.100  0.012     0.100
6   2  3/5  4/15  0.150  0.100     0.100
7   2  3/5  4/15  0.610  0.200     0.100
8   2  3/5  4/15  0.320  0.120     0.100
9   2  3/5  4/15  0.910  0.050     0.100
```